# New Laptop - Backup windows 7 Partition (linux live CD?)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, laptop, partitioning

So I've got a new laptop, but no installation media.
The hard drive has a hidden restore partition, a windows 7 partition, and a small partition for vendor tools.

My goal is to make a backup of the windows 7 partition, get rid of them all, install Ubuntu then reinstall windows 7 from some sort of image.

Does anyone have some help or advice on how to go about doing this, best practices, or a documented walk through?

Comment: I'm interested to see if there's an answer, but personally I seriously doubt that's possible. I'm no Windows expert however.

Comment: Oh, also, I don't think this is really a programming question.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/195386/16115

Comment: Is this an HP laptop?

Answer (score 1):

There is a backup function in Windows 7 that could help you, check it out here:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/663-backup-complete-computer-create-image-backup.html

EDIT: And yeah, I guess this shoul be on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in backup/restore system with a [installer or recovery disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc)

you could, alternatively use a free imaging software that runs in windows - Personally, i've had good luck with [macrium reflect free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp).

Once that's done, i'd suggest resizing and installing, rather than removing the windows 7 partition and installing - since windows 7 will overwrite grub, and its a pain to get linux chainloaded off BCD where windows was installed after linux. You can use EasyBCD if you want the windows bootloader to chainload linux.

Answer (score 1):

I guess with the pre-installed software you would have also got some backup software too. Simply use that to create recovery disks.